# creating a dynamic height for a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple div that contains product information (image, title, description, price, etc...).  I'm using bootstrap (3.x)On the desktop, I use a specific height for the div so everything is equal, displaying in 2 columns.  On Mobile, I only have one column and I'd like to find a way to make the div height dynamic based on the size instead of setting a specific pixel height (descriptions vary and can change the height of the div quite a bit).  Is this possible?  The div's are created dynamically from a database...
Here's the current css - as you can see, I'm setting the height with pixels right now.

```
.prodBox2 { 
height: 300px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding:5px; 
border: 3px solid #666666;
border-radius:25px;
font-family: arial;
font-size: .8em;
color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
.prodImage2 {
float: left;
margin: 10px;
width: 125px;
height: auto;
}
```

Here's a codlin link if it helps:
http://codepen.io/shadowfax007/pen/xVqQNm

Answer (score 1):

Any div's height is dynamic by default. So all you need to do is wrap the height condition in a media query (at screen widths above 768px):

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .prodBox2 {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.prodBox2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
.prodImage2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
}
```

As a side note, you probably want to do some reading on responsiveness, you are currently doing it wrong. In any good responsive design, you do not need to specify heights.

Comment: I would add to this answer that inside your media query, you should also have the overflow set to scroll.  Otherwise, if there is a lot of text so that 300px isn't sufficient, it will overflow out the bottom of your div and look terrible.  `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: Actually, I strongly advice against `overflow:scroll` but `overflow-y:auto` is always a good idea on a fixed height container with variable content.

Comment: Thank to both of you - As for the height, I don't want to use it and am still trying to figure out a way not to (I just started on the site and the height line is temporary until I figure out an alternative - it is not live) - when the products are displayed, the "product boxes" are a different height due to the descriptions being of varying length and don't look right.  I'd hate to have the product "boxes" have to scroll but I definitely see adding it just in case...  If anyone has any ideas on how to make the "boxes" the same height I would love to hear them!

Comment: As for the height tag for desktops, I don't want to use it and am still trying to figure out a way not to (I just started on the site and the height line is temporary until I figure out an alternative - it is not live) but don't see an alternative.  Since the information in each "box" is different and of varying length I don't know how to make them all the same height without specifying it in the css using media queries.  If they are different heights, they don't look right lined up side by side (2 columns of products).  Any suggestions would be welcome :-)